# Trying to resolve a script that allows only numbers is not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript

I have this script that only allows numbers in the targeted input and prevents other characters from being inserted in that input this works in all the browsers except on

Internet explorer 11. The error occurs at line 14 as a syntax error. How can I get this to work on Internet explorer 11?

The error in the console does not give me much info it just say syntax error in red letters and it gives me this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/syntax-error-javascript so in other words it is not giving me really helpful info about the error so I am stuck there.

```js
  document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);
   function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){
  var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
   }
   
   document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
   function pasteTest(event){
    window.setTimeout(() => { //<-line 14
   var characters =event.target.value;
   window.setTimeout(() => {
   if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
   });
    });
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers-only">
```

Comment: what does the error statement say? can you post the error message?

Comment: Thanks for your reply it just say syntax error in red letters and it gives me this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/syntax-error-javascript

Comment: well, I do not know the problem completely but it could be a browser compatibility issue.  I dont think IE supports arrow functions. Just try writing it oldschool

Comment: Thank you for your feed Krishna Prashatt and when you mean old school what are you referring to?

Comment: The same as what inus saha mentioned in answer. The old way of writing functions in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your following function needs to be corrected. IE11 does not support the arrow notation for anonymous functions.

```
function pasteTest(event){
    window.setTimeout(() => { //<-line 14
     var characters =event.target.value;
     window.setTimeout(() => {
        if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
            event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
         }
     });
    });
}
```

the following is the correct version.

```
function pasteTest(event){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
     var characters =event.target.value;
     window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
            event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
         }
     });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply inus saha it gave me the same unknown error aka syntax error and a link again this time it is on line 16 which is referencing to window.setTimeout(() => { at first it did not show so I had to refresh the page to see the error.

Comment: i updated my answer, now it should work. i missed one arrow function there were two arrow functions :)

Comment: it occur in only ie??

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 does not support ES6 features hence the arrow function is not supported.
Change the code snippet to

```
document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);
    function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){
      var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
      if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
    function pasteTest(event){
     window.setTimeout(function() { // change the declaration
       var characters =event.target.value;
       window.setTimeout(function() {
          if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
              event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
           }
       });
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try below code. I made some changes. and it is work for me in ie 11 when I past char in text field. tell me if you have any query.

```js
document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);
    function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode || 0;
      var characters = String.fromCharCode(key);
      if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
    function pasteTest(event){
    
     window.setTimeout(function() { // change the declaration
       var characters =event.target.value;
                                             //remove inner settimeout()
          if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
              event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
           }
       
     });
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers-only">
```